# Issue with unexpected click on "plus" button while running Selenium test

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, click

I have a testAnagrafica() function where I need to verify the existence of the "plus" text and confirm the functionality of the "anagrafica" button but I'm encountering an issue while running a Selenium test where an unexpected click is happening on a "plus" button. I've checked my code and haven't included any click instructions on the "plus" button in the testAnagrafica() function. I've thoroughly examined the HTML code of the page and there doesn't seem to be any other part of the code affecting the click on the "plus" button. I can't figure out why this click is happening. I have also tried using different browsers, cleaning the cache, reboot all, removed the block try/catch, but the problem remains the same. Here's the relevant portion of the code:

```
@Test
void testAnagrafica() {
    WebElement anagraficaButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"content\"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/a/div/h4"));
    anagraficaButton.click();

    try {
        // Wait for 5 seconds
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        String html = driver.getPageSource();
        if (html.contains("Nuovo")) { // If we reach here without errors, we can proceed with other operations
            System.out.println("Anagrafica menu reached");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Anagrafica menu not reached");
            fail("Main menu not reached");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // If an exception occurs during the wait, print the stack trace and fail
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail("Main menu not reached");
    }
}
```

In the terminal output, when running this test, it indicates both that it has entered the "anagrafica" menu and that it has not entered.

Here some HTML source:

```
 <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="navbar-btn">
  <span></span> <span></span> <span></span>
</button>
<nav id="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-header">
    <a href="/home.jsp"><img class="mx-auto d-block"
    src="/img/Logo.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
  </div>

  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li><a href="/anagrafica/anagrafica.jsp"> <i class="fa fa-clipboard-list" area-hidden="true"> Anagrafica </i></a></li>
    <li><a href="/RichiediInterrogazioni"> <i class="fa fa-chart-bar" area-hidden="true"> Interrogazioni </i></a></li>
    <!-- <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-boxes" area-hidden="true">Carichi di Magazzino </i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-exchange-alt" area-hidden="true"> Trasferimenti </i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-undo-alt" area-hidden="true"> Resi </i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-tablet-alt" area-hidden="true"> Ordini </i></a></li>
    <li><a href="venditaAlBanco.html"> <i class="fa fa-cash-register" area-hidden="true"> Vendita al Banco </i></a></li> -->
    <li><a href="/RichiediUtenti"> <i class="fa fa-users-cog" area-hidden="true"> Gestione Utenti </i></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav> 
  
    <!-- Page Content Holder -->
    <div id="content">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <a href="/anagrafica/anagrafica.jsp">
              <div class="service">
                <i class="fa fa-clipboard-list fa-2x" area-hidden="true"></i>
                <h4>Anagrafica</h4>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
            <a href="/RichiediInterrogazioni">
              <div class="service">
                <i class="fa fa-chart-bar fa-2x" area-hidden="true"></i>
                <h4>Interrogazioni</h4>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
```

Comment: _**it indicates both that it has entered the "anagrafica" menu and that it has not entered.**_ - How can the code from `if` and `else` block run in one iteration?!! Unless your `@Test` method is running more than once?

Comment: Can you ensure that the XPath you're using to locate the "Anagrafica" button is unique to the intended button. You can double-check the XPath by using browser developer tools or Selenium IDE to inspect the element and verify that the XPath expression matches only the desired button

Comment: _it indicates both that it has entered the "anagrafica" menu and that it has not entered_: Isn't it a contradictory statement?